# Internet Explorer deletes value of readonly input field on selection

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, input, readonly

I'm currently building a form (take a look [here](https://www.daccusa.org/suggest), please).

I have two columns located at the bottom with input fields; Income and Expenses. If the *Total Income* is lower than the *Total Expenses* the form can't be submitted. Those two fields are located at the end of the two columns.

They have `readonly` activated, because the user shouldn't be able to change the value, however the value has to be passed (a `disabled` input field wouldn't allow that).

```
$('#totalExpenses, #totalIncome').attr('readonly', true);
```

This works great on most browsers, but not Internet Explorer. On IE 9 (and probably lower versions, too), the user is able to select the `readonly`-field and thereby resetting the field. The user isn't capable of typing - only focusing.

I've tried methods like the following code with no luck.

```
$('#totalExpenses, #totalIncome').focus(function(){
    this.select();
});
```

Comment: Try `this.blur();` instead of `this.select();`

Comment: @APAD1 that removes the cursor on focus in IE, which is great, but the value still resets to the placeholder text, when I click it (or use Tab on the keyboard).

Comment: Do you have any idea, @APAD1?

Comment: I don't have a machine with IE available to me, so I can only guess. Have you tried using `.attr('readonly','readonly');` instead of a boolean value? (doubt it would make a difference but worth a shot)

Comment: Didn't do the trick. It's weird, though. The placeholder e.g. _"Total Income"_ doesn't change nor delete on selection. Only the value, which has been dynamically inputted through the fields above, is deleted or reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best - and possibly only - way to achieve the result I wanted was to simply hide a `read-only` version of the *totalIncome* and *totalExpenses* fields, which would then be submitted with the form. I was thereafter able to disable the original *totalIncome* and *totalExpenses* fields.

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that this problem occurs in IE11 if you use objTextarea.**text**('text') instead of objTextarea.**val**('text').